Maven Build Failing with SSLContext Error When Downloading Plugin
I'm trying to execute a Maven build using the following command:
mvn clean install.
I encounter the following error message:
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
[ERROR] The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.2.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.2.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available

Attempted to clear the local repository cache and re-download dependencies.
I expected Maven to successfully download the required maven-clean-plugin and complete the build process without SSL errors, but still encountered the same issue.

Which Maven/JDK version do you use?

@khmarbaise
'mvn -version' :
Apache Maven 3.9.8 (36645f6c9b5079805ea5009217e36f2cffd34256)
Maven home: /usr/share/java/maven
Java version: 17.0.11, vendor: N/A, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8

Are you behind a proxy/corporate firewall ?

@khmarbaise No, but I was trying multiple solutions, and finally what worked for me was deleting java-17-openjdk and then installing it again. However, I still don't know how that happened.

That sounds strange... the installed jdk might be updated by other things ... ?...
